# "Visual Studio C++ 14.0 required" even though I have it installed

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, fastapi

```html
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/   
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for httptools
Failed to build httptools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for httptools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have been following this [tutorial](https://github.com/Sanjeev-Thiyagarajan/fastapi-course) to learn API basics. When I try to run `pip install fastapi[all]` the above error occurs. I have python 3.12 installed and Visual C++ 14.0 as shown in the image below. What could be the issue here?

I have tried this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcI1_e38BWs) to help solve the issue but once I get to the installer it doesn't show me "C++ build tools" as a workload.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWt7R.png)

Comment: That image does not show you have Visual C++ 14.0 installed, only the runtime library.  In order to do a build (compile and link), which the pip package installer wants to do, you need the whole toolchain and not only the runtime.

Comment: The download you're looking for is a "Download Build Tools" button in a dark banner right at the top of the https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ page mentioned in the error.  Don't get confused by all the "great ways to use Visual C++" links farther down the page.  Just download and install the VC++ Build Tools.